# How to add a symbol at the left top corner of standalone document?

Tags: standalone, stackengine

So far, here is my document (I use the `stackengine` package to stack my formulas).

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, class=scrreprt]{standalone}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=15pt}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\stackunder[6pt]
    {\stackunder[6pt]
        {{$\displaystyle f(a+h)$}}
        {{$\displaystyle = $}}
    }
    {{$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot h^k + \frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(a+th) d t$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to add a star at the top left of it, is possible in a margin, like in the following picture:

[image]

On the picture, the margin is grey but I need a white margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$\star$ &
\stackunder[6pt]
    {\stackunder[6pt]
        {{$\displaystyle f(a+h)$}}
        {{$\displaystyle = $}}
    }
    {{$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot h^k + \frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(a+th) d t$}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution with the `amsmath` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  f(a+h)\tag{$\star$}\\
  =\nonumber\\
  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot h^k +
  \frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(a+th) d t\nonumber
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you don't want parenthesis around the star, you can use `\tag*{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  f(a+h)\tag*{$\star$}\\
  =\nonumber\\
  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot h^k +
  \frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(a+th) d t\nonumber
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, if you want to avoid entering `\nonumber`, you can instead use the * version of `gather`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  f(a+h)\tag*{$\star$}\\
  =\\
  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot h^k +
  \frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(a+th) d t
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change the outer `\stackunder` into a `\tabbedstackunder` (using the `tabstackengine` package), the star can be added as a new column in the stack, of the form `\tabbedstackunder{\star& ...}{&...}`.  Note I also employed `\stackMath` so that all stacked material would automatically be treated in math mode (no `$` delimiters needed).

Note the temporary patch to `tabstackengine`, until a newly introduced bug in the `listofitems` V1.4 package is remedied.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, class=scrreprt]{standalone}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=15pt}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%% TEMPORARY tabstackengine PATCH UNTIL listofitems V1.4 BUG GETS FIXED
\makeatletter
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\@TABstackonunder}{\readTABstack}{\expandafter\readTABstack\expandafter}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%
\stackMath
\begin{document}

\tabbedstackunder[6pt]
    {\star &\stackunder[6pt]
        {{\displaystyle f(a+h)}}
        {{\displaystyle = }}
    }
    {&{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}\cdot h^k + \frac{h^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(a+th) d t}}
\end{document}
```

[image]